# How to create a stacked bar chart with 2 numeric variables in R using ggplot, grouped by 1 factor variable - take 2, with standard error?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I asked this question a while ago:

[How to create a stacked bar chart with 2 numeric variables in R using ggplot, grouped by 1 factor variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485276/how-to-create-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-2-numeric-variables-in-r-using-ggplot-gr)

And got a really great answer from akash87, but I've now been asked if it would be possible for me to add standard error bars into the graphs? I've added them into my dataframe, which now looks something like:

```
df<-data.frame(month = c("Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Mar", "Apr", 
                      "May", "Jun", "Jul"), 
              site = c("Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Clarach", 
                     "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach"), 
              organic = c(10,20,30,40,50), 
              inorganic = c(90,80,70,60,50), 
              se = c(2,3,1,4,3))
```

I know it seems counterintuitive to have one SE for two different variables, but as they are percentages and calculated from the same data, the variation is the same.. hope that makes sense. If it would be easier I can give an example of my original dataset, before I broke it down into means by month and added in the SE column.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```r
df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c("organic", "inorganic")) %>%
  mutate(se = ifelse(name == "inorganic", NA, se)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = site, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(min = value - se, max = value + se)) +
  facet_grid(~month) +     
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste(x, "%"))
```

[image]

Comment: What you've done is what I would like mine to look like, but when I try to work this with my actual dataframe it doesn't come out like that :( I have no idea why not. 

I'm not sure how to add an image into a comment, but I just have one column for borth, one for clarach, and the values go up to 800% :/

I've tried just adding geom_errorbar(aes(min = value - se, max = value + se)) + in the original code from @akash87 but it leaves me with 2 error bars in each column that don't overlap with the column itself.

Comment: @mbroadribb you could edit your question to attach a picture

Comment: Hi Allan, sorry that was my bad! I was adding month as a function by mistake so it was adding a bracket which shouldn't have been there - I've fixed that now. Thanks so much for your help!!